# [UPDATED, not solved]Simulating a Buck converter

Tags: dc, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, pspice

Im trying to simulate a buck converter done in class to see if this fits what the theory says it would be, It must receive 110 V and send to the load around 60V and 20 A,  the circuit is:
[image]

And with the next pspice circuit code

```
VS  1   0   DC  110V
VY  1   2   DC  0V  
Vg  7   3   PULSE (0V 20V 0 0.1NS 0.1NS 27.28US 50US)
RB  7   6   250
LE  3   4   681.82UH
CE  4   0   8.33UF  IC=60V
L   4   8   40.91UH
R   8   5   3
VX  5   0   DC  0V 
DM  0   3   DMOD
.MODEL DMOD D(IS=2.2E-15 BV=1800V TT=0)
Q1  2   6   3   QMOD
.MODEL QMOD NPN (IS=6.734F BF=416.4 BR=.7371 CJC=3.638P CJE=4.493P TR=239.5N TF=301.2P)
.TRAN 1US 1.6MS 1.5MS 1US   UIC
.PROBE
.options abstol = 1.00n reltol = 0.01 vntol = 0.1 ITL5=50000
.FOUR  20KHZ  I(VY)
.END
```

It was expected to see something like this
[image]
But Im getting this outputs
[image]
this are too much different between the expected graphs, the I(VX) would be ok except for the fA values instead of A. V4 means the load voltage so its supposed to be around the 60 V. The component values were calculated in class so Im assuming these are ok.
Why does not match the two graphs? (discarding print errors, and wrong components values)

**UPDATE**
The logic of the netlist is fine, I play with the values of the trans operator changing from

```
  .TRAN 1US 1.6MS 1.5MS 1US UIC
```

to

```
  .TRAN 1US 1.6MS 1.5MS 1US
```

Giving the next output
[image]
That is more or less the idea except for the fA values- and the fact it seems to be showing only one pulse of the source.
So its some sort of options error, what other values could be adjusted?

Comment: Can you check if Vg is what you expect?

Comment: Post a picture of the schematic in the simulator, not a 'pretty' schematic. It's easier to find errors that way. The voltages and currents are in femto-units, so it looks like something isn't switching and it's just showing noise.

Comment: Make sure you have a ground. Some simulators assume a very high value resistor to ground on floating nodes so you get tiny currents rather than an error.

Comment: @Linkyyy It's possible the asker wrote the netlist manually, too. You're right that it looks like noise, though.

Comment: I performed my own calculations to help confirm the values you set up in your circuit. I was easily able to get the results you wanted, with the values you provided above, using LTspice. It just works. However, I used a schematic entry so my node numbers are different. Check your spice deck, I suppose?

Comment: @Hearth: Well hopefully not if he doesn't know how to debug it..

Comment: @Linkyyy In this I avoided the schematic to prevent errors.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany , the netlist indeed has a ground in the node 0

Comment: @Hearth, but this give me more noise...

Comment: @riccs_0x Yes, I saw that on the netlist, but that's not the way the simulation is behaving.

Comment: @xuva , yes Vg its 20V

Comment: @riccs_0x: Why did you accept an answer if you havn't solved it yet? No one is going to look at this question because it has an accepted answer. Or DID you solve it? Then why do you keep editing the main text?

Comment: @Linkyyy, I have seen other questions that are still open after selecting an aswer. I selected these answer because its the best (and only) answer, but I dont consider this is already solved. And I think this is ok, because if I make another question based on this one then its marked as a duplicate, I cant close this  to open aonther because there is no reason to close, and since the system says the option of selected as best answer can be undone. But I take your comment in consideration.

Comment: @riccs_0x: well i only see 1 difference between your netlist and Jonk's and that is the line "Q1 2 6 3 0 QMOD" where he has a 0 which you don't.

Comment: @Linkyyy, You are right, let me check it!

Comment: @Linkyyy, nop it was not, after all I think Im gonna leave the question as it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just entered your schematic into LTspice with the following circuit and results (current in \$R\$.)

[image]

(I changed the .TRAN card to provide \$200\:\mu\text{s}\$ instead of \$100\:\mu\text{s}\$ of span on the graph.)

As you can see, the results are what you expected to see. Yes, I did use your options card, as well (not shown on the schematic above.) However, I was not able to use *ITL5=50000* as LTspice doesn't recognize that one.

---

Here's my netlist:

```
VS 1 0 110
Vy 1 2 0
Vg 7 3 PULSE(0 20 0 .1n .1n 27.28u 50u)
RB 7 6 250
Le 3 4 681.82µ
Ce 4 0 8.33µ
L 4 8 40.91µ
R 8 5 3
Vx 5 0 0
Dm 0 3 DMOD
.MODEL DMOD D(IS=2.2E-15 BV=1800V TT=0)
Q1 2 6 3 0 QMOD
.MODEL QMOD NPN (IS=6.734F BF=416.4 BR=.7371 CJC=3.638P CJE=4.493P TR=239.5N TF=301.2P)
.ic V(4)=60
.tran 0 1.7m 1.5m 1u uic
.options abstol = 1.00n reltol = 0.01 vntol = 0.1
```

---

I'd recommend downloading and installing LTspice to see if you can replicate the results you want with it. If so, then perhaps there's something else with respect to the spice program you are using that you need to adjust. If you don't want to use LTspice for some reason, then I'd recommend disclosing the spice program you are using to get the results you show. Perhaps someone else will be familiar with it and can guide you.

Comment: He used the tag "pspice" so i would assume it is what he is using. +1 for effort, it is definitely some kind of setup/schematic error as you concluded.